# How do you page through the jump list?

Tags: scrolling, navigation, jumplist

With the `:jumps` command, you can display the list of jump locations to aid navigation. That is you can use `CTRL_O` and `CTRL_I` to jump backwards and forwards respectively.

However, my jump lists appear to be very long. When I execute the `:jumps` command, my jumps are displayed with the `-- More --` prompt at the bottom. How do I navigate/scroll through this information?

My problem is that I'm using `G` to move to the bottom of the list, but when I then re-enter normal mode, the next key I press begins macro recording (perhaps this is an issue with one of the plugins I am using).

Answer (score 1):

I realised the information is available in the `:help more-prompt` section.

I think a plugin might be causing auto-macro recording.